# Flutter bluetooth printer with TSPL commands not working

Tags: flutter, dart, printing

Is there any support dependency that can handle TSPL command? i just search in pub.dev for the flutter dependency, i don't see it can support TSPL command.
https://fluttergems.dev/printing/

All of that only support for ESC/POS or TSC. not for TSPL

Only try this dependency from https://fluttergems.dev/printing/ in our local project

Btw, this is my printer spec XPrinter (XP-4601B).